# How to substitute arguments in a regex pattern? (Javascript / React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple regex pattern which I'm using to validate a string.

I want to use the same regex in order to produce a string, using the exact same regex.

For example, I have the following regex: `const regex = ^action:(?<whatAction>(WRITE|READ|DELETE))$`

Is there any function `substitute` so: `substitute(regex, {whatAction: "WRITE"})` will yield `action:WRITE`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add examples of the desired input/output combo?

Comment: No, there is not. Just write `.replace(regex, "action:WRITE")`